# Confused with greater than and less than operators

Tags: python-3.x, operators

I'm new to coding and I'm learning how to code in python. What I can't get my head around is why the '<' is read as '>' when a number comes before it.

e.g.

```
if 4 < people <=14:
    print('You need a minibus')
```

why is this code read as greater than 4 people but less than 15.

can someone explain to me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The arrow only points to the smaller side. so "4<people" means true if 4 is less than people. It becomes true for people=5,6,7,....
The second condition people<=14 is true as long as people is less or equal 14.
people=...12,12,14 becomes true. people=15,16... becomes false.

May be this helps: the wide side of the < is on the bigger side.

Comment: so can this code be written as 'if people > 4 and <=14' ?

Comment: Never tried it that way. May be is works like this: 'if (people>4 and people<=14)' using the variable people in both comparisons.